# on/in a dirt road

Tags: prepositions, collocations

Which preposition is correct in each of the sentences of dirt road?

> 1. The grass grows on/in the dirt road.
> 2. There is a little bush in/on that dirt road.

Comment: It should be on.

Comment: An obstacle is said to be *in* the road.   *Outta my way, you're in the road!*

Comment: @TRomano I thought that was BrE; I mean "you're in the road". So what if it was not about driving and obstacles and rather about describing the road or contrasting it with another to show the differences? If I did not put it clear enough, could a scenario ever exist for "grass grows on the dirt road"?

Comment: Sure. Grass can grow *on* a dirt road. It often does, between the tire tracks and to either side.

Comment: TRomano is correct.  Things that should be or might sometimes be in/on the road are most often "on" the road.  "There's some hot tar on the road.  The road crew is painting the center-line on the road.  There is a traffic jam on Second St.  I drive my car to work on Second St."

Things that are obstacles or should not be in/on the road are often "in" the road. "There's a chicken in the road.  My car stalled and I left it in the road.  "

Comment: So whether the grass grows on or in, and whether the bush is on or in, depends on your interpretation of where grass and bushes should or should not be.  And, of course, that can change from situation to situation.  "I swerved into the ditch because a little bush was growing in the road."  Or "If you look closely you can see the cute little bush that grows on that road."

Comment: In AmE, I'm hard-pressed to find a context in which it would be appropriate to say *in the dirt road*. The only time I've ever used the phrase is in a way similar to @TRomano's 1st comment—i.e. there is an object in [the middle of] the road—e.g. *There's a bunch of litter in the middle of the road. But there's nothing incorrect about using *on* in that context—e.g. *There's a bunch of litter scattered on the road.*

Comment: Additionally, when you use the actual name of the street, such as Second Street, you generally don't use "in" by itself.  You would be more likely to use "in the middle of".  For example you would not say, "There is a boulder in Second Street."  You would say instead, "There is a boulder in the middle of Second Street."

Comment: @EllieK It's not only not at all incorrect to say *My car stalled and I left it on the road*, but I'd say in AmE, it's the most common phrasing.

Comment: @Giambattista I would disagree.  Although I understand both are acceptable.  I left my car on the road sounds incorrect to me.

Comment: @EllieK Perhaps it wouldn't strike you as incorrect if the road were named rather than being generic?— *My car stalled and I left it on Main Road.*

Comment: And there's the Beatles song, *Why don't we do it in the road?* http://www.songfacts.com/detail.php?id=161

Answer (score 1):

They are somewhat interchangeable, as are many prepositions. In your specific examples I'd go with *on*:

> 1. The grass grows on the dirt road.
> 2. There is a little bush on that dirt road.

A quick ngrams search reveals that in Modern English, the phrasing *on the road* is more common than *in the road*, which is true in [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+road%2Con+the+road&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20road%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20road%3B%2Cc0), [BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+road%2Con+the+road&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20road%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20road%3B%2Cc0), and [English overall](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+road%2Con+the+road&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20road%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20road%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

Both usages can be correct.  They are not, however, interchangeable.  Use "in the road" if you wish to convey that the object is blocking the road, keeping in mind that "in the road" is a shortened version of "in the middle of the road".

In fact, the only time things can be "in the road", is when they are in the middle of the road, figuratively speaking.  Things can never be "in the side of the road" or "in the edge of the road".  Although they can be "on the side of the road" and "on the edge of the road".

Use "on the road" if the object is expected to be on the road.

One drives around that which is in the road.  One drives over/past that which is on the road.